# Unity Scene open on build?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, scene

Which scene opens in a unity android .aab file when you build it?
The scene you had open while building or scene number 1 of build settings?

I really need to know, because I let the wrong scene opened while building
thanks!

Comment: scene 0 ...... not 1

Comment: Please note that there is no rule to open a specific scene "in a unity android .aab file". Unity always starts with whatever scene is at index 0, regardless of the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There is one rule of opening unity built scene.
Open a Build Settings, Click on check box for scenes to build you want, and See the index in red box.

0 is always first open scene. (you can determine a sequence of scenes using drag and drop)